# Get User Profile using Profile Manager in Visual Web Part SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am receiving the error "Access Denied: Only an administrator may retrieve a count of all users." though I am using SPSecurity.RunwithElevatedPrivileges
What am I  missing ? Please help.

```
 private UserProfile GetUserInfo(string AccountName)
   {
       UserProfile profile = null;

       SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
                {


                    SPServiceContext serviceContext = SPServiceContext.Current;
                    UserProfileManager profileManager = new UserProfileManager(serviceContext);
                    if (AccountName != string.Empty)
                    {
                        if (profileManager.UserExists(AccountName))
                        {

                            profile = profileManager.GetUserProfile(AccountName);
                        }
                    }
                    //else
                    //{
                    //    profile = profileManager.GetUserProfile(SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.RawSid);
                    //}
                });
       return profile;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to retrieve the user profile with the help of below code

```
 SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges( 
                delegate() 
                { 
                    using (SPSite thisSite = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Site.Url)) 
                    { 
                        HttpContext tmp = HttpContext.Current; 
                        HttpContext.Current = null; 
                        SPServiceContext serviceContext = SPServiceContext.GetContext(thisSite); 
                        UserProfileManager mgr = new UserProfileManager(serviceContext, true); 
                        users.Text += "The total number of user profiles available:  " + mgr.Count;                                
                        HttpContext.Current = tmp; 
                    } 
                } 
            );
```

Source : http://weblogs.asp.net/sreejukg/access-denied-error-when-retrieving-user-profiles-count-from-sharepoint

Answer (score 0):

yes, you need to generate a new context.
In you old code :

```
SPServiceContext serviceContext = SPServiceContext.Current;
UserProfileManager profileManager = new UserProfileManager(serviceContext);
```

You generate a new UPM with you current context, so you **RunWithElevatedPrivileges** is useless.

In you new Code :

```
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate() 
{
 using (SPSite thisSite = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Site.Url)) 
 {
   [...]
   SPServiceContext serviceContext = SPServiceContext.GetContext(thisSite); 
   UserProfileManager mgr = new UserProfileManager(serviceContext, true);
```

You get a new Context with Eleveted (because you instantiate a new SPSite in the ElevatedPrivileges) and thats why you can now use the UPM